# $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ bounded measurable, with $C$, $0<\alpha<1$ such that $\mu(\{|f|>s\}\leq Cs^{-\alpha}$, for all $s$. Prove $f\in L^1$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

So, I know we want to show that $\int f d\mu<\infty$, and I believe this question is supposed to be easy once you rewrite $\int fd\mu$ in terms of the measure of a set, but I can't find what that's supposed to be.

(Sorry to give so little to work with, measure theory is painful for me)

I notice this is getting downvoted a bit, feel free to comment why you think this post deserves it (trying to better understand the community here).

Comment: $\int |f|d\mu=\int_0^{M} \mu(\{|f|>s\})ds$ if $|f| \le M$.

Comment: @geetha290krm what does $ds$ mean in this case? Integral with respect to Lebesgue measure with $s$ as the variable? Regardless, I see that having that would give us $\int |f|d\mu\leq \int^M Cs^{-\alpha}ds$, and, if this a Lebesgue integral, I see that that is finite.

Comment: Yes. $ds$ is integral w.r.t. Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @geetha290krm Very nice, I looked back at my notes and realized that is incredibly common convention, sorry for missing that

Comment: @cable Remember $s\mapsto \mu(\{|f|>s\})$ is a function from $[0,+\infty)$ to $[0,+\infty]$. Therefore it should be understood simply as the Lebesgue integral of a real-valued function with real-valued variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is bounded by $M$, then $\int_\Omega f d\mu=\int^M\mu\{x|f(x)\leq s\}ds$, and by supposition, we then have $\int fd\mu\leq \int^M Cs^{-\alpha} ds=C(-\alpha) s^{-\alpha-1}|^M_0$, which is finite, thus $f\in L^1$.